# run vlc in a Docker image to send a video stream via rtsp protocol

Tags: bash, video, docker, vlc, rtsp

I am using Docker for a project. The goal is to play a video in VLC and send the data stream via the RTSP protocol, so that the other machines(user) can see the video on live in their machines.
the video, the Dockerfile and the bash file are in the same folder. here is a bash file (simulate_video_stream.sh) I use:

```
# Two facultativ parameters : -f <nameOfTheVideoFile> and -i <URL_Output>
SCRIPTPATH=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd -P );
name=$SCRIPTPATH"/counter.mp4";
sdp="rtsp://:8554/flux";
while getopts "f:i:" OPTNAME
do
   case $OPTNAME in
      f) name=$OPTARG;;
      i) sdp=$OPTARG;;
   esac
done
sout="#transcode{vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp="$sdp"}";
vlc -vvv $name --sout $sout
```

And here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y vlc

COPY simulate_video_stream.sh /tmp/
COPY counter.mp4 /tmp/
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/simulate_video_stream.sh"]
```

The build is a success by **"sudo docker build -t test ."** I am hoping to use it with the two parameters defined in the bash file, like **"docker run test -f namevideo.mp4 -i rtsp://:8554/test"**
But it returns "write pipe: bad file descriptor"
What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the host OS and what architecture?

Comment: I used Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to give an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for executing the script.

Second, you can't run `vlc` as `root`.

Third, you can't provide a file as argument and expect `vlc` to open it from *inside* the container, when the file is on the *host*. You need to mount it first.

Fourth, you need to quote `$sout` variable, otherwise it will begin with `#` and bash will ignore it as an *argument* and *won't* pass it to `vlc`.

Fifth, if you want the stream to be available outside, you will need to [expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/expose-incoming-ports) the port.

Make the following changes:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y vlc

RUN useradd -m vlcuser

COPY simulate_video_stream.sh /tmp/
COPY counter.mp4 /tmp/
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/simulate_video_stream.sh"]
```

Script `simulate_video_stream.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Two facultativ parameters : -f <nameOfTheVideoFile> and -i <URL_Output>
SCRIPTPATH=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd -P );
name=$SCRIPTPATH"/counter.mp4";
sdp="rtsp://:8554/flux";
while getopts "f:i:" OPTNAME
do
   case $OPTNAME in
      f) name=$OPTARG;;
      i) sdp=$OPTARG;;
   esac
done
sout="#transcode{vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp="$sdp"}";
su vlcuser -c "vlc -vvv $name --sout '$sout'"
```

And run the container as:

```
docker run -v $PWD/namevideo.mp4:/tmp/namevideo.mp4 -p 8554:8554 test -f /tmp/namevideo.mp4 -i rtsp://:8554/test
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. the build was a success. but when I did the `docker run` command that you offered, it seemed that the vlc worked then quitted immediately. And I cannot see the flux by using [rtsp://my ip adress:8554/test] in another computer in the same subnet.

Comment: plus, if I want to test it with the counter.mp4 in the same folder as the bash file and the Dockerfile, is it right that I replace all the 'namevideo.mp4' in the 'docker run' command with 'counter.mp4'? thank you very much.

Comment: what I expected is that the `docker run` will open a vlc player and play the video, during this time we can visit it via the link. I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Nehal J Wani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185217/5144316) worked for me with a small change: I had to use the "clvc" command (to run VLC without user interface) instead of "vlc", otherwise VLC would close without initiating the stream properly.

So, the last command in `simulate_video_stream.sh` is:

```
su vlcuser -c "cvlc -vvv $name --sout '$sout'"
```